# do while loop exiting in jOptionPane

Tags: java, joptionpane

Consider the following code. For some reason, even after hitting the `NO` button, it's exiting the do while loop. I recently introduced the `recentPurchaseAmount` variable and it stopped working after that. Even removing that is not making it work now.

Variables like purchaseAmount , recentPurchaseAmount are double type initialized to 0.0. itemNo, itemCheck are integer type variables.

```
do {
    purchaseAmount = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
        "Enter the Item Purchase Amount"));
    recentPurchaseAmount = recentPurchaseAmount + purchaseAmount;

    if (onepty.budgetAmountVerify(recentPurchaseAmount)) {
        itemNo++;
        itemCheck = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
            "Finished Purchasing Items Purchase Amount?",
            "Say Yes or No", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION); 

        remainingBal = onepty.remainingBalance(recentPurchaseAmount);        
    }
}   while(itemCheck == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
    "Total items purchased are " + itemNo + 
    "\n and the remaining balance is : " +remainingBal+"" ,
    "This is the Title",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
```

Comment: You click `NO`, so you get the `NO_OPTION`, which is not equal to `YES_OPTION`, so the `while` condition is `false` and the loop exits. Where is the problem?

Comment: @RealSkeptic Actually, when I click on YES, then also it's exiting the loop . This is the problem

Comment: Well, you should prepare a [mcve] to demonstrate that, because we can't test this code. It should not exit the loop when you click YES, unless something changes `itemCheck` in between.

Comment: Would you like me to provide the method details I am using? Will that be enough for testing? Please let me know

Comment: Your condition for staying in loop should be while you press NO not YES

Comment: @DanielJipa So do you see any logical bug in my current code?

Comment: I think the popup should reappear until you press yes (finish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while(itemCheck == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);`will be a more suitable condition.

Comment: Awesome. This condition worked for me. Wondering what was wrong with the previous one and why compiler was treating it in a different manner.

Comment: @Dan it wasn't a compiler problem, but a logical one in your code.